# Rails search with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple rails search form that will look through all posts and match some keywords, but I'd also like it to match some attributes as well.

I have this as my view:

```
<%= form_tag(grant_applications_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Terms" %>


  <%= check_box_tag :search, "Pending", params[:search] %>
  <label>Pending</label>

  <%= check_box_tag :search, "Granted", params[:search] %>
  <label>Granted</label>

  ...
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-rimary" %>

<% end %>
```

Model:

```
  def self.search(query)
    where("grant_request LIKE ? OR contact_email LIKE ? 
           OR contact_person LIKE ? OR status LIKE ?", "%#{query}%","%#{query}%",
           "%#{query}%","%#{query}%")
  end
```

Controller:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @grant_application = GrantApplication.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    else
        @grant_application = GrantApplication.all.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end
end
```

Any suggestions as to how I should add in the checkbox filters when searching?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to get keyword matching search system with a normal search input text field.

1) Make a new text input field with :keyword attribute and the parameter is just :search as you already used.

2) allow :keyword attribute on the controller if it's Rails 4+ or on the model if it's not Rails 4.

3) Never directly use user's input. 
Always filter it for security reasons. 
Use 'before_filter' in the controller. 
Check if it's empty, have html tags or javascript scripts, and so on. 
Usually I sanitize it with a helpful method of 'sanitize' gem.

4) now, get user's keywords by separating each word by a blank space.

5) write your search query with keywords in the model

6) perform and return it.

I will answer more in detail if you ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

**All search is about to create the correct sql statement**. At Rails you can have helper classes for that and make your life easier.

1) The more needed lines, those that you may need in other search classes, put them at utils.rb:

```
module Utils

  def is_like(query)
    "%" + query + "%"
  end

  def case_insensitive_search(query)
    "lower(#{query}) like :#{query}"
  end

end
```

2) Then, for the model. They can be more complex than 3 fields...  like this helper class called search_posts.rb:

```
include Utils

class SearchPosts
  attr_reader :where, :what, :order

  def initialize(author_id, publish, query, order_by_title, desc_order)
    @where = ""
    @what = {}
    @order = ""

    commit_search(author_id, publish, query, order_by_title, desc_order)
  end

  private

  def commit_search(author_id, publish, query, order_by_title, desc_order)

    unless author_id.nil?
      @where << "author_id = #{author_id}"
      @what[:author_id] = author_id
    end

    unless publish.nil?
      unless @where.blank?
        @where << ' AND '
      end

      @where << "publish = #{publish}"
      @what[:publish] = publish
    end

    unless query.blank?
      unless @where.empty?
        @where << ' AND '
      end

      @where << "(#{case_insensitive_search(:title)}"
      @what[:title] = is_like(query)

      @where << ' OR ' << "#{case_insensitive_search(:content)})"
      @what[:content] = is_like(query)
    end

    if order_by_title
      @order << 'title '
    else
      @order << 'updated_at '
    end

    if desc_order
      @order << 'DESC'
    else
      @order << 'ASC'
    end
  end

end
```

3) At you controller, just catch the params you are passing and build the search. Remember all is about to create the correct sql statement and your code can do it for you. ;)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
def search # or any other action...
  if params[:query_posts].present?
     # this is the only couple of lines you will have to be changing to query anything about your model
    search = SearchPosts.new(nil, true, params[:query_posts], true, false) 
    @posts = Post.where(search.where, search.what).order(search.order)
  end
end
...
end
```

The result sql statement that will be passed to active-record is:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE ((lower(title) like '%query%' OR lower(content) like '%query%')) ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```